# Python beginner query

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I've been trying to limit the `wrong_answers` to maximum of six times. That is if the user inputs answers 6 times wrong, he gets a print message.

If I use the `If`  statement, python code checks it only the first time it runs. Which means it doesn't come back to the `If` statement again. (`If` statement is us from `bird_random = random.choice(Animals.bird_list)`)

If I use **Function**, it displays the `wrong_answers` limit reached message correctly, however it continues to display code lines below. (i.e will continue to display further questions.)

**Question**
 1. What am I doing wrong? What is the solution
 2. How Can I make my code more "Professional"?

```
class Animals:
bird_list = [
    "Grey Parrot",
    "American Crow",
    "Bald Eagle",
    "Black Vulture"
]

dog_list = [
    "German Shepherd",
    "Bulldog",
    "Poodle",
    "Labrador",
    "Golden Retriever"
]

cat_list = [
    "Turkish Angora",
    "Siamese",
    "Bengal",
    "Persian",
    "Ragdoll"
]
```

#### Main file.

```
from Animal_List import Animals
import random


guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False
right_answers = 0
wrong_answers = 0


bird_random = random.choice(Animals.bird_list)
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    bird_guess = input("Enter the guessed bird: ")
    if bird_random == bird_guess:
        print("Birdsie, you guessed it!")
        right_answers +=1
        break
    else:
        guess_count += 1
        wrong_answers +=1

guess_count = 0 # Reset guess_count
dog_random = random.choice(Animals.dog_list)
while guess_count < guess_limit: 
    dog_guess = input("Enter the guessed dog: ")
    if dog_random == dog_guess:
        print("Dullocks, you guessed it!")
        right_answers +=1
        break
    else:
        guess_count += 1
        wrong_answers +=1

guess_count = 0 # Reset guess_count
cat_random = random.choice(Animals.cat_list)
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    cat_guess = input("Enter the guessed cat: ")
    if cat_random == cat_guess:
        print("Dullocks, you guessed it!")
        right_answers +=1
        break
    else:
        guess_count += 1
        wrong_answers +=1


last_cause = "You've got {} right. It took {} wrong answers to get it right"
print (last_cause.format(right_answers, wrong_answers))
```

Comment: There's no "wrong answers limit reached" message in your code. Furthermore, you're never checking the value of wrong_answers, only guess_count in each while loop. I am not sure you copy pasted the right piece of code.

What you could do is encapsulate all the whiles in another while loop, verifying the number of wrong answers at each iteration. Then you should just manage one variable in order to know which nested while loop to go in during each iteration, e.g. put if to_guess == 'bird' right before your first while loop here, and set to_guess to dog when bird found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the 3rd while loop..

from `while guess_count < guess_limit:`

to `while guess_count < guess_limit and wrong_answers < 6:`

Comment: That helped. Thank you Ashish